# Django Polling App TypeError between Nonetype and datetime.datetime

Tags: python-3.x, django, datetime

I am practicing Django Polling App and get the following error when I try my admin site to open questions

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'

My models.py

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        # now = timezone.now()
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

It seems to work if I replace DateTimeField by DateField and use timezone.now().date() but the tutorial does not mention it.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: the `self.pub_date` is returning the value ***`None`*** and hence the error

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the polls.sqlite3 file (the database) as apparently any field structure changes do not get saved or migrated in the migrations process. Dont know if this is an issue. However, after recreating the database file, the problem is solved.
Thank you for your help.